# Complex ARel query

Tags: sql, ruby, activerecord

I've got a complicated query that I can't wrap my head around (using either sql or ActiveRecord)  Here are my models:

```
class Contact
  has_many :profile_answers
end

class ProfileAnswer
  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :profile_question
end

class ProfileQuestion
  has_many :profile_answers
end
```

I'm trying to find the number of ProfileAnswers for two contacts that have the same `value` for a particular ProfileQuestion.  In other words:

> Get the total number of profile answers that two contacts have answered with the same value for a particular profile_question

I don't want to make multiple queries and filter as I know this is possible with Sql only, i just don't know how to do it

I had considered a self join of `profile_answers` on `profile_question_id` then filtering by `value` being equal, but i still can't wrap my head around that.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean "two **specific** contacts" or "**any** two contacts" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT profile_question_id)
FROM 
  ( SELECT profile_question_id
    FROM ProfileAnswer an
      JOIN ProfileQuestion qu
        ON qu.id = an.profile_question_id
    WHERE contact_id IN ( id1, id2 )
    GROUP BY profile_question_id
           , value
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
  ) AS grp
```

And the `JOIN` seems not be used. So, if `ProfileAnswer.profile_question_id` is `NOT NULL`, this will suffice:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM 
  ( SELECT profile_question_id
    FROM ProfileAnswer
    WHERE contact_id IN ( id1, id2 )
    GROUP BY profile_question_id
           , value
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
  ) AS grp
```

---

EDITED for two specific contacts (with ids `id1` and `id2`).

Added the `WHERE` and changed the `COUNT (DINSTINCT )` to `COUNT(*)`.

---

Perhaps this version with JOIN can be more easily adapted to ActiveRecord.

**Using `JOIN`**

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM ProfileAnswer a
  JOIN ProfileAnswer b
    ON a.profile_question_id = b.profile_question_id
    AND a.value = b.value
WHERE a.contact_id = id1
  AND b.contact_id = id2
```

Comment: awesome, think that works!  Just trying to translate that into ARel to make it nicer to look at.  Just one question.  I'm assuming then that the `having count(*) = x` is such that `x` should be the same as the number of contacts that I'm checking against?  So i could make this generic for `x` number of contacts?

Comment: @brad: Exactly. If you want to find identical answers from x persons, just change `2` into `x` and put the x ids in the `IN (...)` list.

Comment: @brad: I've added a version with `JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I ended up doing it, thanks again @ypercube:

```
class ProfileAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.for_contacts(*contacts)
   where :contact_id => contacts.collect(&:id)
  end

  def self.common_for_contacts(*contacts)
    select(:profile_question_id).for_contacts(*contacts).group(:profile_question_id, :value).having("count(*) = #{contacts.length}")
  end

  def self.common_count_for_contacts(*contacts)
    find_by_sql("select count(*) as answer_count from (#{common_for_contacts(*contacts).to_sql})").first.answer_count
  end
end

# Usage
ProfileAnswer.common_count_for_contacts(contact1, contact2[, contact3...])
```

Still had to use a find_by_sql in the end for the nested select... not sure if there's any way around that ??

Also annoying that find_by_sql returns an array, so I had to use `.first` which then gives me the object that has my `answer_count` property on it.